# DataTable to XML

Tags: xml, linq, datatable, using

I have a datatable, I want to construct an xml.
I am able to get so far...need some help.

DataTable

```
factory,  item
---------------
1,  123
1,  345
2,  999
```

xml should look like

```
<test>
 <factory>1</factory>
 <items>
   <item>123</item>
    <item>345</item>
 </items>
</test>

IEnumerable<XElement> files = from f in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                 select new XElement("test", 
                     new XElement("factory", f["factory"]), 
                     new XElement("item", new XElement("item",f["item"])));
```

above query gives me a flat xml

```
<test>
 <factory>1</factory>
 <items>
   <item>123</item>   
 </items>
</test>
<test>
 <factory>1</factory>
 <items>
   <item>345</item>   
 </items>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns an `XElement`, not an `IEnumerable<XElement>` (which is logic if you just want one `<test>`, I think :

```
var result= new XElement("test", dt
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .GroupBy(m => m["factory"])
                                 .Select(f =>
                                        new XElement("factory",
                                            f.Key,
                                            new XElement("items", f.Select(g =>  
                                                new XElement("item", g["item"]))))));
```